# Parser error and initmap is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to use google map directions to return directions and time to me after a form is submitted and then save the distance and time to the database along with other relevant information.  I have an html site that I can click on waypoints and display the map without issues. However when I use try to do it after form submission and make it self firing I am getting errors and no output.  I cannot figure out why the same exact code on one page runs and on another it says parser error and initmap is not a function. I have marked the parser error in the code as a comment. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
if (!empty($_POST['employee_id'])) {
print_r($_POST); echo "<br>";
if(!empty($_POST['orders_id'])){
          foreach($_POST['orders_id'] as $order_id) { 
           $lat = $_POST['latitude'][$order_id];
          $lon = $_POST['longitude'][$order_id];
          $waypoints[] = '{location: "' . $lat  . ',' . $lon  .'", stopover: true}';
          }  //End foreach($_POST['orders_id'] as $order_id)
  print_r($waypoints);
  ?>

  <script>
function initMap() {
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 13,
  center: {lat: 27.714617, lng: -82.393298}
}); // close var map

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    }); //close event listener
  }// close initMap

  var waypts = <?php echo json_encode($waypoints); ?>;
 // function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    //var waypts = [];
    //var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
    //for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
      //if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
    //    waypts.push({
     //     location: checkboxArray[i].value,
     //     stopover: true
     //   });
     // } 
//    }

    var startLocation = {lat: 27.714617, lng: -82.393298};
    var endLocation = {lat: 27.714617, lng: -82.393298};

    directionsService.route({
      //origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      //destination: document.getElementById('start').value,
      origin: startLocation,
      destination: endLocation,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
        // For each route, display summary information.
        var total = 0;
        var totaltrip = 0;
        var time = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          total += route.legs[i].distance.value;
          time += route.legs[i].duration.value;

          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
              '</b><br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
        } 
        totaltrip = total/1606.47058823; 
        totaltime = (((routeSegment-1) * 120) + time)/60;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = totaltrip + ' ' + totaltime + " minutes";
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }   //<--- Parser error???
  function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
      total += route.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
  }
 initmap();
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8_rOr43NZxg-bzVbvL5YEsVholHAeAB4&callback=initMap">
</script>
<?php    

} //End if(!empty($_POST['orders_id'])){
} // End if (!empty($_POST['employee_id']))
```

Comment: Capitalization matters. `initmap` vs `initMap`

Answer (score 0):

Your callback for the Google Maps API says `callback=initMap`

Therefore when the `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` it is expecting the function `initMap()` to be available to run.

The following solve the problem:

A: On pages where no `initMap()` function is needed then add the script **without** the callback. ie: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR_KEY}`

B: If the callback is included on every single page but not really needed. ie: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR_KEY}&callback=initMap` then simply add a blank function to that page, ie:

```
<script> function initMap() { console.log('i am not needed here'); } </script>
```

C: Is that a typo? In the example above note that `initmap()` is not the same as `initMap()` (cammelcase).

Comment: Yes that was a typo.

Comment: RE: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Take a look at the The DirectionsRequest object literal section.

Comment: make sure yours look like this, comma's, brackets, ect...
waypoints: [
    {
      location: 'Joplin, MO',
      stopover: false
    },{
      location: 'Oklahoma City, OK',
      stopover: true
    }],

Comment: I am getting the following returned  {location: "27.713465100000000,-82.415157099999990", stopover: true}

Comment: That is php though. I cannot get anything on console.log as if it is not firing.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => {location: "27.713465100000000,-82.415157099999990", stopover: true}
    [1] => {location: "27.708788800000000,-82.479897100000020", stopover: true}
)
              var waypts = ["{location: \"27.713465100000000,-82.415157099999990\", stopover: true}","{location: \"27.708788800000000,-82.479897100000020\", stopover: true}"];

Comment: Make waypts an ARRAY in Javascript, add brackets. For example 

  var waypts = [<?php echo json_encode($waypoints); ?>];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169116/discussion-between-christian-zagarskas-and-david).